How to Vertically Align an Author Attribution with the Longest mbox
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\oddsidemargin=-20pt \textheight 9in \textwidth 6.25in
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{verse}
\Large

\lipsum[23]
\vspace{10pt}

\bfseries
\mbox{If you can dream, and not make dreams your master;} \\
\mbox{If you can think, and not make thoughts your aim;} \\
If you can meet with Triumph and Disaster \\
\mbox{And treat those two imposters just the same; \ldots}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{flushright}
---Rudyard Kipling
\end{flushright}
\end{verse}
\end{document}

with the output:

QUESTION: How, if possible, may I automatically extend the author attribution farther to the right so that ends vertically aligned with the last character of the longest mbox; in this case, ``... not make dreams your master;''?
Thank you.

have you considered using the verse package? why are you putting every line in a box? use something like chngpage if you want to alter margins for part of a page. or set things up in a box/coffin etc. i.e. one rather than one per line.

Of course, something that's out of the page boundaries is unacceptable.
You don't need verse for the job.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  textheight=9in,
  textwidth=6.25in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[23]

\begin{center}
\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
\begin{varwidth}[b]{\textwidth}
If you can dream, and not make dreams your master; \\
If you can think, and not make thoughts your aim; \\
If you can meet with Triumph and Disaster \\
And treat those two imposters just the same; \ldots
\end{varwidth} \\[10pt]
--Rudyard Kipling
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


